Consumir Web Service Soap en .NET 2008
como están ? disculpen la molestia, necesito ayuda para consumir un web service Soap en mi proyecto desarrollado en .NET (VS) 2008 framework 3.5, ya que no se como empezar para poder adaptarla a un reporte. Podría alguien comentarme los pasos a seguir para enviar el request y tener la respuesta xml, ocupo asp.net para mi front. Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida. (La wdsl no es publica)

No existe tal cosa como .NET 2008. Puede ser que haya Visual Studio 2008 (en realidad no lo recuerdo), pero definitivamente no .NET, que va de la versión 1 a la 4.8: listado de versiones de .NET

Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

click derecho sobre el proyecto -> agregar -> agregar referencia de servicio -> wcf -> ahí escribes la url del WSDL

la solución que me brindaste es correcta, lastimosamente no es una web service publica por tal no me deja agregar de esa manera. necesito crear todo por medio de codigo, Gracias.
